# Javascript Objects / Prototypes. Is my understanding wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, prototype

I have been reading about Javascript Classes / Objects / Prototypes and come from a OOP background so I now wish to use Objects in Javascript.

However I think I am misunderstanding something. When using objects in the past in VB.net for example you created your object and was able to populate it by using dataclasses.

But here in the land of javascript things dont execute in the way I was expecting due to this async thing.

So I create my prototype as below and call the appropriate function but the function says it has fnished (but hasnt because it hasnt had a response from the $.post that is taking place, my code continues as null values and I dont get the info I want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <button onclick="gogetperson()">Hello</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function Person() {
        this.firstName = '-';
        this.surname= '-';
        this.alias = 0;
    }
    Person.prototype.name = function() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.surname
    };

    Person.prototype.getPerson = function(personid)
    {
        var query = $.param({personid: personid});
        var url = 'custom/person_get.php';

        $.post(url, query, function (response) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
            this.firstname= obj['rFirstName'];
            this.surname = obj['rLastName'];
            this.alias = obj['rAlias'];

            console.log(this.firstname);
        });

    }    

    function gogetperson() 
    {
        var myPerson = new Person();
        myPerson.getPerson(1)

        console.log(myPerson.firstName);

    }
</script>
    <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

So when my button runs the gogetperson function it finishes but has not got the data yet. 
The console.log in the $.post section returns to the console the first name of my person but too late for me to use it.

Am I using prototypes in the wrong way?

I want to be able to use javascript as an object when getting data.

Or am I totally wrong.

My reason for wanting to use it this way was it seems the better choice over php objects.

Should I use PHP objects instead?

I ultimately want to get data from a mysql database and easily change my webpage with jquery and javascript.

Comment: $.post is asynchronous. when executing console.log in function gogetperson(), they haven't got the callback function from $.post yet. so nothing will be printed out in this line.

Comment: clearing up some terminology: "Objects" in Javascript are simply a primitive key/value pair datatype, what is called "dictionaries" or "maps" in other languages. Prototypes can be added *to* objects, to impart a class-like identity, but that identity is *wholy determined* by the prototype, so unlike in classical hierarchical inheritance, JS lets you change the prototype at runtime and because *every instance defers to the prototype*, which you just changed, *every instance now behaves in accordance with the new API*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one thing ,that is http call using `$.post` is asynchronous and it  is not a blocking call. In order to get values back from `getPerson()` method, you have to pass a `callback ( or  function)` in that function to get the result back but it is not a recomended approach . You can read about promises and use them because they are great.
However using a callback, you can do something like.

```
Person.prototype.getPerson = function(personid, cb)
{
    var query = $.param({personid: personid});
    var url = 'custom/person_get.php';

    $.post(url, query, function (response) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
        var person = new Person();
        person.firstname= obj['rFirstName'];
        person.surname = obj['rLastName'];
        person.alias = obj['rAlias'];

        console.log(person.firstname);
        cb(person);

    });

}
```

And then you can call it  like,

```
var myPerson = new Person();
function showPersonDetails(person){
     console.log(person.name())
}
myPerson.getPerson(1, showPersonDetails);
```

Comment: Ok. got that. and it works. without resorting to lots of terms that I dont have in my head yet, the basic principle you are showing me here is when the data has been returned, hand the whole thing off to another function that carries on the job.
I see how this works. For my purpose it should do exactly what I want.
Thanks to all who answered particularly Zohaib. Happy Days!

Comment: yeah. right... But I suggest you to read about Promises and  jquery's `$.when()` function.

Comment: Tried the when function and got the same result. I probably wasn't using it correctly.